# How to create a new function on window or self(which has assigned interface Window by lib.d.ts)?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, web-worker, typescript

obviously I am trying to get facebooks async init working. Doing it, I need to create a function on object window called "fbAsyncInit". I am having simillar problem, when writing web workers, because there I want to use self.postMessage but self is once again having as its interface interface Window.
However I try to do it, the typscript compiler is not happy with me adding a field to window which is not specified in Window interface.
I tried to do it like this at first:

```
interface WindowFB extends Window { 
    fbAsyncInit: ()=>any;
}

declare var window: WindowFB;
```

that didn't help so I tried some other things and managed to get type checker happy, but it seems like it is just bugged(because for the solutions it is not happy 100%). 
Does anybody know what the right solution for this might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'Window' interface is open. You can just write:

```
interface Window {
    fbAsyncInit: () => any;
}

window.fbAsyncInit();
```

Due to some bugs around lib.d.ts, this won't quite work in the TypeScript Playground, but the command-line compiler should be able to accept this.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am working in Visual studio 2012, so I've mostly had in mind getting rid of the errors there.